# how to extend the project model with geoengine capability?

Tags: model, geolocation, project-management, odoo-10

How can I extend the Project or task model on odoo 10 with geoengine capability so I can display the location of Project or task in google map dashboard ?

Answer (score 1):

there is already modules base_geolocalize that store partner location using Latitude and Longitude, you can just do same with project and task,  it auto 
populate from address fields.